# Spring ExceptionHandler returning 500 Internal error

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I'm working on a RESTful server using Spring 3.4.0.  I have a couple of APIs working.  Now I'm adding error handling.  I'm starting with the basic `@ExceptionHandler` within my Controller class.

I created an my own APIException class:
    `public class APIException extends RuntimeException`

I created an `ErrorInfo` class.

And final added the `handleAPIException` method in my controller.  The values here are hard-coded.  I'll change that once this is working:

```
@ExceptionHandler(APIException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorInfo handleAPIException(APIException e) {
    ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setCode(3344);
    errorInfo.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    errorInfo.setMessage("test message!");
    errorInfo.setDeveloperMessage("test developer message!");
    errorInfo.setMoreInfo("no more info");
    errorInfo.setRequestId("testrequest123");

    return errorInfo;
}
```

Now when I run this and step through using debugger, it does get to this function and this function executes all the way though till the end.  But then on the client side I get the following html response instead of a nice json representation of `ErrorInfo`.  I've tried changing the `handleAPIException` response to ModelAndView instead of `ErrorInfo`, but that didn't help either.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is co.company.here.exception.APIException

**type** Exception report

**message** Request processing failed; nested exception is co.company.here.exception.APIException

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is co.company.here.exception.APIException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

**root cause**

```
co.company.here.exception.APIException
    co.company.here.controller.BusinessController.createBusiness(BusinessController.java:114)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Comment: `and this function executes all the way though till the end` Are you sure? Put some log statements in it and double check.

Comment: Well, you're setting the status to BAD_REQUEST which is 400, but Tomcat is throwing a 500...

Comment: Update: actually realized that I was not on spring version 3.4.0 as I had mentioned in the question.  In pom.xml spring.version was set to 3.0.5.RELEASE.  I updated it to 3.2.1.RELEASE and this now works perfectly.  Thanks for your comments.  I'll close this question.